# Sqlite3 Fetching takes More time in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios4, sqlite, xcode4.3

While I fetching data from sqlite3 using some JOINS and Group by Conditions, it takes More Time.

The table has 30000 records

Is There Any optimising Way To Fetch Large Junk of Data from SQlite?

Comment: Given it's impossible to show 30000 records in an iphone screen, why would you even try to do that? Why don't you figure out other way to do it?

Comment: I AM NOT DISPLAYING 30000 RECORDS ACTUALLY TABLE CONTAINS 30000 RECORD AMONG THAT I AM GOING SHOW ONLY FEW RECORD

Comment: Can you add the table schema, and also the SQL statement that executes too slow?

Comment: this is the query i have been using                                                                                                                                     select distinct FirstName || ' ' || LastName As FullName,AreaName,contacttype,DoctorId as Custid,AreaId,TerritoryName,flag from contact inner join plandetail on custid=doctorid where  strftime('%Y-%m-%d',plandate)  ='2012-09-03' and userid='22' and status = 'E'   AND AreaId = 85803  order by FullName                                                        i have join many tables when the table grow the fetching speed is affecting

Answer (score 1):

You can limit sqlite to return only the top n results and offset by m to get the later entries as your user scrolls down: SELECT someColumn ORDER BY someOtherColumn LIMIT n OFFSET m

This would be much more efficient.  Should I elaborate more?